# Cannot find interface declaration for class

Tags: objective-c

I refactored some code and in one subclass there is no error and in the second subclass I get this error.

In the first case, the interface looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ResultsHeaderView.h"
#import "ManagingView.h"
#import "CommonEventsTableVC.h"
@class ResultCell;

@interface ResultsTableVC : CommonEventsTableVC <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,  resultsHeaderDelegate>{
```

In the second case, with the error, the interface looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Constants.h"
#import "ManagingView.h"
#import "ResultsHeaderView.h"
#import "CommonEventsTableVC.h"
@class ResultCell;

@interface FavoritesTableVC : CommonEventsTableVC <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,  resultsHeaderDelegate>{
```

The complier error on the @interface line in the second case is "Cannot find interface declaration for 'CommonEventsTableVC', superclass of 'FavoritesTableVC'.

I can't see the problem.

UPDATE

I was able to compile without errors using this code, but the alternative (shown below) doesn't work for some reason:

CommonResultsTableVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
//#import "MapController.h"
//#import "DataInterfaceObject.h"
#import "ManagingView.h"
#import "ResultsHeaderView.h"
@class MapController;
@class DataInterfaceObject;
@class ResultCell;

@interface CommonEventsTableVC : UIViewController {

@private
    DataInterfaceObject *dataInterface_;
    MapController *mapController_;
    id<managingView> managingViewDelegate_;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<managingView> managingViewDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) DataInterfaceObject *dataInterface;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MapController *mapController;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andController:(id<managingView>)_managingViewController;

@end
```

ResultsTableVC.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CommonEventsTableVC.h"

@interface ResultsTableVC : CommonEventsTableVC <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,  resultsHeaderDelegate>{

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController_;
    UITableView *tableView_;

}

...
```

FavoritesTableVC.h

```
#import "Constants.h"
#import "CommonEventsTableVC.h"

@interface FavoritesTableVC : CommonEventsTableVC <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,  resultsHeaderDelegate>{

...

}

...

@end
```

Here is the alternative, which doesn't work. I don't know why. Importing the class header file should be a viable replacement of the @class reference, but all sorts of errors occur. These errors are even in the class files referenced by the import statements.

CommonResultsTableVC.h alternative (fails)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "MapController.h"         // uncommented
#import "DataInterfaceObject.h"   // uncommented
#import "ManagingView.h"
#import "ResultsHeaderView.h"
//@class MapController;
//@class DataInterfaceObject;
@class ResultCell;
```

Comment: Are there any other errors?  What about in Constants.h.

Comment: Show what's in CommonEventsTableVC.h. Maybe it really doesn't contain a declaration of the `CommonEventsTableVC` class. Ask Xcode to show you the preprocessed file. There will be a lot of stuff from the frameworks in there, but hopefully you'll be able to find the problem, too.

Comment: Yes, are you sure it wasn't accidentally renamed by your refactoring?

Comment: You declare CommonEventsTableVC in a file called CommonResultsTableVC.h, but import CommonEventsTableVC.h according to this question. Is that a typo?